# d3 - Getting an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using the following code to visualize temperatures:

```
nv.addGraph(function() {

var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
            .margin({left: 100})        // Margin space
    .margin({bottom: 130})
            .useInteractiveGuideline(true)  // Activate tooltips
            .transitionDuration(500)    // Transition delay
            .showLegend(true)           // Show the legend (Turn on/off line series)
;


chart.xAxis    
        .axisLabel('Datum')
        .rotateLabels(-45)
        .tickFormat(function(d) { 
        // 01/12/2013 12:00 Uhr
        return d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L')(new Date(d))
    });


chart.yAxis     
        .axisLabel('Temperatur')
        .tickFormat(d3.format('.01f'))
;


var tempHumidData = getTempHumidData();


d3.select('#chart svg') 
        .datum(tempHumidData) 
        .call(chart) 
;


nv.utils.windowResize(function() { chart.update() });
return chart;
});



function getTempHumidData() {
    var tempOutside  = []

    // Data is represented as an array of {x,y} pairs
    // Hint: The UNIX timestamp from the DB must be multiplied by 1000
    //       as the JS date datatype works with milliseconds
    <?php
            for($i=0; $i < count($tempOutside); $i++)
    {
            echo "tempOutside.push({x: $tempOutsideDate[$i], y: $tempOutside[$i]});\n";
    }
   ?>



    // Line chart data should be sent as an array of series objects.
    return [

            {
                    values: tempOutside,
                    key: 'Temperatur Aussen',
                    area: true
                    //color: '#FFa02c'
            }
    ];
}
```

But when I'm executing this in the browser I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

The following line is marked in the debugger:

> tempOutside.push({x: 2018-02-27 21:00:09.779805, y: -10.9});

So I don't understand where is my problem. Where can I specify the right format for this line?

Comment: I think the last part of your code got cut off, cant see `getTempHumidData` function.

Comment: yes you're right. Thanks. I've completed the code

Comment: I don't know much about nv charts, but do you know what scale type is being used behind the x axis? My guess is linear which might have a hard time parsing a date obj.

Comment: The only property for the x-axis I found is the following: `chart.xAxis    
        .axisLabel('Datum')
        .rotateLabels(-45)
        .tickFormat(function(d) { 
        // 01/12/2013 12:00 Uhr
        return d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L')(new Date(d))
    });`

Answer (score 0):

What you're getting here is a standard JavaScript error, and it's because your code is invalid. I imagine it's failing because it's trying to treat `2018-02-27 21:00:09.779805` as a number. Here is a reproduction of this error:

```js
const myArray = [];
myArray.push({ x: 2018-02-27 21:00:09.779805, y: 3 });
```

Instead this should either be a `string`, or most likely a `date`. Try constructing a date out of it instead like this:

```
tempOutside.push({x: new Date("2018-02-27 21:00:09.779805"), y: -10.9});
```

Comment: Now I'm getting the error **Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list** for the following line `tempOutside.push({x: new Date(2018-02-28 17:30:05.459777), y: -7.3});` This is my definition: `echo "tempOutside.push({x: new Date($tempOutsideDate[$i]), y: $tempOutside[$i]});\n";`

Comment: @l0cksmith that's a different problem. I can't see anything obviously wrong. You may want to create a new question or use linter to spot errors. Alternatively read up what they mean. In this case you're missing a close `)` somewhere